# Please help me with my code (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

hp = 100
eh = 100



while hp > 0 and eh > 0:

    print("Action? (attack, heal, nothing):")

    act = input(">")

    attack = random.randint(1, 30)

    heal = random.randint(1, 15)




if act == "attack" or "Attack":
    eh = eh  - attack
    print(attack)
    print("eh = %s" % eh)

elif act == "heal" or "Heal":
    hp = hp + heal
    print("You have healed %s points" % heal)
    print(hp)
```

Why is it that when I type heal, it runs the attack part as well?  Even when I type neither attack nor heal it still runs the attack section.

Comment: Meet a useful [method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower): `if act.lower() == "attack":`

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `or` is incorrect. It's acting as if you had:

```
if (act == "attack") or ("Attack"):
```

Any non-empty string evaluates as `True`.

Instead use:

```
if act == "attack" or act == "Attack":
```

Or even:

```
if act in ("attack", "Attack"):
```

Answer (score 0):

In this conditional:

```
if act == "attack" or "Attack":
```

The part after the or always evaluates to true.

```
>>> if "Attack":
...     print "Yup."
...
Yup.
```

What you probably meant is

```
if act == "attack" or act == "Attack":
    eh = eh  - attack
    print(attack)
    print("eh = %s" % eh)

elif act == "heal" or act == "Heal":
    hp = hp + heal
    print("You have healed %s points" % heal)
    print(hp)
```

Though a better way is

```
if act.lower() == "attack":
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I assume that the if and elif part is indented to fit into while loop.

The reason behind it firing Attack part all the time, is your condition:

```
if act == "attack" or "Attack":
```

It basically equals to

```
if (act == "attack") or ("Attack"):
```

Which means the same as

```
if (act == "attack") or (True):
```

So its actually always true.

To make it work you should repeat "act == " part before "Attack too" so it s

```
if act == "attack" or act == "Attack":
  eh = eh  - attack
  print(attack)
  print("eh = %s" % eh)

elif act == "heal" or act == "Heal":
  hp = hp + heal
  print("You have healed %s points" % heal)
  print(hp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, I think your if statement should be

```
if act == "attack" or act=="Attack":
```

As it is,

```
if "Attack"
```

will always evaluate as true, so the attack portion will always run.

I might also recommend doing

```
act.toLower() == "attack"
```

This way you can do a single comparison and ignore case sensitivity. Just a thought.

Comment: It is just `.lower()` in Python not `.toLower()`